# how use regex use to add text header to second column?

Tags: regex, replace

I have this text:

```
date:14/05/06
box
radio
mouse
date:25/05/06
keyboard 
antenna
```

I want this result:

```
date:14/05/06
box&14/05/06
radio&14/05/06
mouse&14/05/06
date:25/05/06
keyboard&25/05/06
antenna&25/05/06
```

Comment: What makes you think you need to use regular expressions for this? What language are you programming in?

Comment: You should use a parser for this, although regex may be a part of the solution.

Comment: regex pcre (notepad++)

Comment: You have 2 options, option 1, write a very specific regex for the exact scenario, that means you need to know the exact number of lines. The reason why is that even though you could do a repeated match with regex, you cannot do a repeated capture group with regex. You'll just wind up capturing the last thing.

Comment: I believe this actually *might* be possible in Notepad++, since it supports recursive expressions, but a regular expression is really a bad tool for this job. A Python script to do this is certainly less than 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++, replace this:

```
^(date:)([\/\d]+)((?:(?:\r?\n)+\b(?!date:)[^\r\n:&]+$)+)
```

with this:

```
\1\2\3&\2
```

You'll have to run it several times: it won't do it in a single pass. You can see (at least the first iteration) [here](https://regex101.com/r/wR7wR6/1).